# Going from trigonometric functions to algebraic functions.

Tags: trigonometry

How do you simplify the function $\arctan(\cos x)$ so that it does not use any trigonometric functions? The closest answer I was able to come up with is $\pi/4\cos x$, but that was simply a guess from looking at the function. Furthermore, $\cos x$ is obviously a trigonometric function, so this would not work.

Comment: If the unknown angle in question is $\theta$, and if you presume that $\cos(x) = a,$ then $\displaystyle \cos(\theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2 + 1}}.$  This leads $1 + \cos^2(x) = \sec^2(\theta)$.  Alternatively, you have from the original constraint that $\cos(x) = \tan(\theta).$ Personally, I don't see how either of these relationships can be converted into a relationship between $x$ and $\theta$ that does not involve trig functions.

Comment: Re previous comment, I suppose that since there are Taylor series for both the Sine and Cosine functions, a Taylor series for the Tangent function could be constructed.  Then, you would have that the constructed Taylor series for $\tan(\theta)$ equals the Taylor series for $\cos(x)$.

Comment: How did you get $\frac \pi {4 \cos x}$? It clearly doesn't fit with the expression (Ok, I see it was a guess for a reason!). Also, I am not sure how I'd answer this question , because I'm not sure what you are allowing apart from trigonometric functions. Using complex numbers one can make this into $e^{i...}$, but apart from that, if you're talking about the answer being a polynomial in $x$ or a rational function in $x$ (or even the square root of one or something like that ), it should be possible to show this is not the case, to end optimistically.

Answer (score 1):

Solving trig(inverse trig(x)) is easier than inverse trig(trig(x)), because the final result of the former can be a ratio of sides and the final result of the latter has to be an angle.

Since $-1 \leq \cos x \leq 1$,

$-\pi/4 \leq \arctan \cos x \leq \pi/4$

There may not *be* an easy expression, but your guess at least has the right bounds.

I think the only approach that stands a chance is using complex functions.

$$\cos z = \frac{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}{2}$$

$$\arctan z = -\frac{i}{2} \ln \frac{1+iz}{1-iz}$$

Substitute the former in for $z$ in the latter, and you get a mess, but at least it is an algebraic mess, albeit with exponentials and logarithms.

Comment: But if you calculate that complex algebraic mess, you obtain $\arctan(\cos x)$ again, so I think there does not exist a solution for the problem of the original poster.

Comment: Not if you don't substitute trig functions back in.  It's the best I could come up with.  I'm not sure better is possible.

Comment: But you cannot calculate a logarithm of a complex number without involving trigonometric functions. A logarithm of exponentials in complex field is just another way to write an inverse trigonometric function of trigonometric functions. It is the same thing to write $x^{1/2}$ instead of $\sqrt x$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\;\alpha=\arctan(\cos x)\;,\;$ it follows that

$\tan\alpha=\cos x\;\;,$

$\tan\alpha=\pm\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+\tan^2x}}\;.$

I think it is not possible to obtain the value of $\;\alpha\;$ without using any trigonometric function.